# Not receiving certain notifications on OnePlus 3 running Android Marshmallow unless I wake the screen

Tags: notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I was wondering if anyone might have any suggestions on how I could disable the Android Marshmallow doze/deep sleep mode that is default on new devices to save battery. I have a OnePlus 3 and have made every effort to check that all my notifications for calendar, whatsapp, emailing, etc. are set to both vibrate and make a sound, disabled all battery optimization features for apps, tried using screenlock wake apps to avoid missing notifications, and more. However, I am still unable to get notifications for whatsapp, emails, calendar reminders and events once my screen goes to sleep or I lock then phone and it's idle (so after about 15-30 minutes of it sleeping), but calls and texts seem to come through fine (or at least I haven't noticed these being an issue as much). This is a HUGE inconvenience, as my main reason to have a smartphone is so I can check emails, calendar events and such right as I receive them, and not only when I wake up my screen (which then bombards me with all my previous missed notifications from hours before). I have a feeling this is an android 6.0 issue and not due to the OnePlus 3, because it's been reported in other sites and by people with phones also using either this OS or lollipop. My older Samsung galaxy S4 running kitkat never had these problems, and at this point I'm very keen on going back if I can't get my new phone (or this OS, as I predict) to notify me right away even when my screen is locked and phone asleep (I can't always remember to check it especially if I'm busy at work). I am willing to root the phone and change settings if that's an option, but I would please like to see if you guys have any other suggestions for allowing my phone to receive notifications right away even when in sleep mode/idle/dozing. Thank you for your time in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up rooting and using the "dumpsys" command to disable doze mode. That has done it for me! I found the details on the widespread issue and resolution here: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/push-notification-issues.451149/